# Пользовательский прогресс-бар

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animation

Я пытаюсь реализовать пользовательский прогресс-бар на сайте. В такой форме, что он должен иметь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда пользователь выбирает Круг, Я хочу, чтобы линия (и только линия, а не круги) заполнялась  цветом, пока она не достигнет этого круга, и, наконец, красная точка должна появиться в центре  третьего круга, если пользователь нажал на третий круг:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понятия не имею, как лучше, проще подойти к этому.
Я уже попробовал сделать это на чистом `CSS`, `jQuery` и `javascript`, но никто не может воссоздать этот эффект. Я должен использовать два изображения и постепенно накладывать их, пока я не достигну выбранной точки?
Я должен полностью не использовать изображения и попытаться воссоздать форму с `CSS` или `SVG` и изменить цвет определенного раздела?
Я  знаю, что обычно в вопросах здесь должен быть код, но я не могу его показать, потому что  понятия не имею, какой подход применить и часы исследования онлайн  с бесконечным количеством решений, не помогли мне, так как  не подходят к моей задаче.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Custom shape progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27051337/7394871)  от участника  [@David Matos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2419967/david-matos).</sub>

Comment: что-то я не понял... вы задали вопрос, а потом в конце дали ссылку на ответ к нему... wat?

Comment: @Олександр этот топик в рамках программы ассоциации с англоязычным сайтом. Задал вопрос там David Matos .Ответ будет оформлен позже. У нас почему-то не работает пример ответ ---- проверяю

Comment: прошу прощения, я так понял вы просто делаете локализацию инт. вопросов на русском? Тогда еще раз извините

Comment: @Олександр Ничего страшного. Сейчас главное разобраться, почему у них работает пример, а у нас нет

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051337/custom-shape-progress-bar/27054259#27054259

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вариант на css

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b-someclass {
  text-align: center;
}
.b-someclass-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
.b-someclass-inner:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 6px;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: -3px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.b-someclass-inner input {
  display: none;
}
.b-someclass-inner input + label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
.b-someclass-inner input + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: -25% 0 0 -25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: tomato;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: .25s;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}
.b-someclass-inner input:checked + label:after {
  background: tomato;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.b-someclass-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 0;
  height: 6px;
  background: tomato;
  transition: .35s;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.b-someclass-inner input:checked + label ~ .b-someclass-line {
  left: 50px;
}
.b-someclass-inner #check-2:checked + label ~ .b-someclass-line {
  width: calc(100% / 6);
}
.b-someclass-inner #check-3:checked + label ~ .b-someclass-line {
  width: calc(100% / 6 * 2);
}
.b-someclass-inner #check-4:checked + label ~ .b-someclass-line {
  width: calc(100% / 6 * 3);
}
.b-someclass-inner #check-5:checked + label ~ .b-someclass-line {
  width: calc(100% / 6 * 4);
}
.b-someclass-inner #check-6:checked + label ~ .b-someclass-line {
  width: calc(100% / 6 * 5);
}
```

```html
<div class="b-someclass">
<div class="b-someclass-inner">
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check-1" checked>
    <label for="check-1"></label>    
    
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check-2">
    <label for="check-2"></label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check-3">
    <label for="check-3"></label>
   
   <input type="radio" name="check" id="check-4">
    <label for="check-4"></label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check-5">
    <label for="check-5"></label>
    
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check-6">
    <label for="check-6"></label>
    
    <div class="b-someclass-line"></div>
</div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Это довольно просто с помощью CSS и добавлением немного jQuery.

```js
// Добавить обработчик кликов к исходным точкам
$("UL.progress LI").click(function(e) {
   // Отменить выделение текущего выделения
   $("UL.progress LI.selected").removeClass("selected");
   var  newDot = $(this);
   // Какую точку мы выбираем?
   var  newProgressWidth = newDot.index();
   // Анимируйте новую ширину красной линии
   $("UL.progress LI.progressline").animate(
       {'width': (newProgressWidth * 90) + 'px'},
       400,
       function() {
          // Когда закончите, выберите новую точку
          newDot.addClass("selected");
       });

});

// Добавьте черные и красные полосы в качестве дополнительных элементов <li>
// без обработчика кликов
$("<li>").addClass("blackbar").appendTo("UL.progress");
$("<li>").addClass("progressline").appendTo("UL.progress");

// Выберите первую точку
$("UL.progress LI").first().addClass("selected");
```

```css
UL.progress {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

/* черные точки */
UL.progress LI {
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* первая черная точка не имеет пробела слева */
UL.progress LI:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

/* красная точка при выборе */
UL.progress LI.selected:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


/* черные и красные линии сзади*/
UL.progress LI.blackbar,
UL.progress LI.progressline {
    z-index: -2;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 30px;    /* 60 (диаметр) / 2 */
    width: 450px;  /* 5*60 + 5*30 (диаметр точки и зазор) */
    height: 4px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

/* чёрная линия */
UL.progress LI.blackbar {
    z-index: -2;
    background-color: black;
}

/* красная линия прогресса */
UL.progress LI.progressline {
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: red;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Example progress bar<br/>

<ul class="progress">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27054259/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>